# Python Extract Table from URL to csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Extracting the "2016-Annual" table in http://www.americashealthrankings.org/api/v1/downloads/131 to a csv. The table has 3 fields- STATE, RANK, VALUE. Getting error with the following:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'http://www.americashealthrankings.org/api/v1/downloads/131'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find('2016-Annual', {'class': 'STATE-RANK-VALUE'})

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')

    if len(cells) == 3:
        STATE = cells[0].find(text=True)
        RANK = cells[1].find(text=True)
        VALUE = cells[2].find(text=True)

    print  write_to_file
    f.write(write_to_file)

f.close()
```

What am I missing here? Using python 2.7

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you never define `write_to_file` or set anything to it

Answer (score 1):

you code is wrong

this 'http://www.americashealthrankings.org/api/v1/downloads/131'  download
csv file.

download  csv file to local computer, you can use this file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''

import urllib2

url = 'http://www.americashealthrankings.org/api/v1/downloads/131'

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    output.write(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Beautifulsoup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you need to pass a string to be parsed on initialization. However, `page = urllib2.urlopen(req)` returns a pointer to a page.

Try using `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')` instead.

Also, the variable `write_to_file` doesn't exist.

If this doesn't solve it, please also post which error you get.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is because your pointing to a file that is already a csv - you can literally load that URL in your browser and it will download in CSV file format ---- the table your expecting though, is not at that endpoint - it is at this URL:

http://www.americashealthrankings.org/explore/2016-annual-report

Also - I dont see a class called `STATE-RANK-VALUE` I only see `th` headers called `state`,`rank`, and `,value`